# What's the equivalent call() apply() of JavaScript in C?

Tags: javascript, c, function, reflection, call

In Java it is:

- `java.lang.reflect.Method`

In JavaScript it is:

- `apply()` ⟶ more like `java.lang.reflect.Method`
- `call()`  ⟶ more like function pointer in C

In C it is:

- `type (*varname)(Type1 label1,Type2 label2,Type3 label3)` ⟶ `call()`
- What is the equivalent in C of `apply()` or `java.lang.reflect.Method`?

------------i am pretty slow, the answer from eyalm:

the caller perceive the callee as :

- int (*a)(char value);

and the callee perceive the stack frame as :

- Type (*varname)(Type1 label1,Type2 label2,Type3 label3 ...)

---- am i right?

Comment: come on, don't do this to me , it is a very targeted question. i do my unskillful research indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function pointer:

```
int (*a)(char *);
```

you can call with ... wait for it ...

```
a("ggffgfgg");
```

Comment: you are super senior in my perspective, thanks ...

Comment: logically it is, but is it the official way?(i am sorry to say so but concerned )

Comment: @Johnny: It is one of two ways of calling a function via a pointer.  The other is `(*a)("ggffgfgg");`.  Once upon a long time ago, before there was a C standard, this was the only way to call a function via a pointer to function.  The C standard allows the answer given by eyalm (and it is probably the more widely used notation these days — though I prefer the old method myself, but then I'm archaic too).

Comment: That's just an equivalent to `call()`, not `apply()`. For `apply`, you would have to do something funny like putting all the arguments into a struct and passing that by value...

Comment: thanks until 15 characters,DCoder.

Comment: but does there any dynamic struct? i know i can construct an byte array according to some number which indicate the length.

Comment: thanks, Jonathan Leffler, there just too many senior and archaic people that are still alive, so happy it is true. and what is the old method you keeping for yourself?